# Can I implement a traffic identifiter (layer 7) based on netfilter hook functions (layer 3)?

Tags: traffic, netfilter

I want to write a simple traffic identifiter based on netfilter hook functions because I think netfilter hook is easier to implement.  I want this using regular expression to identify some layer-7 traffic such as ftp,p2p. But , considering ftp traffic is on layer 7 while netfilter hooks work on layer 3 , I wonder if it is possible ? If so , is that proper for the identifiter do lots of work on layer 3 aiming at some pattern match on layer 7? thx a lot .

Answer (score 0):

There is the [l7-filter](http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/) project, which is based on netfilter. It has lots of predefined regexes.